# What alternative methods have been proposed for proving the (FS groups) classification theorem?

Tags: group-theory

I am told that John Conway thought that the Classification of Finite Simple Groups Theorem should have been done "inside-out". What sources would be useful in understanding the alternative forms of proof for the classification theorem? I am working with a general physical theory that may contain a mathematical structure upon which the sporadic groups operate. Would this probably lead to a totally new form of proof, or would it relate to one of the already proposed alternatives?